# Porting Python 2 Unicode to Python 3

Tags: python, unicode, python-3.x, porting

I'm currently porting some code from Python 2.x to 3.x and I have come to a hitch. When I try to change:

```
base = unicode(base, FSENCODING, "replace")
```

to what I think 3 wants, which is:

```
base = str(base, FSENCODING, "replace")
```

it doesn't work saying that `str` can not decode. If I try:

```
base = b'\x80abc'.decode(base, FSENCODING, "replace")
```

I get an error saying that this can only take two arguments instead of the three that I have provided.

Comment: You should include the error message, and preferably the whole traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
base = b'\x80abc'.decode(FSENCODING, "replace")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
base = str(base, FSENCODING, "replace")
```

Is correct. You can also do:

```
base = base.decode(FSENCODING, "replace")
```

It's the same thing.

What is going wrong is impossible to say without the error message.